# propel:diff task generates unnecessary SQL sentences for all fields/tables

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and Propel 1.6 with a MySQL 5.1.

Every time I make little changes on `schema.xml` (add one field in one table for example), I use to execute:

```
php symfony propel:build-all --classes-only --env=dev
php symfony propel:diff --env=dev
php symfony propel:up --env=dev
```

In the second step, the task always generates SQL sentences for ALL the fields in ALL tables of the type `alter table change`fieldfield`integer not null` or drop/create constraints that didn't change at all:

```
ALTER TABLE `pedido_linea` CHANGE `id` `id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `product` CHANGE `norma_id` `norma_id` INTEGER(11);
...
ALTER TABLE `pedido_linea` DROP FOREIGN KEY `pedido_linea_FK_2`;
ALTER TABLE `pedido_linea` ADD CONSTRAINT `pedido_linea_FK_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
    REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

It seems like Propel doesn't read MySQL's fields' attributes correctly and treats them as changed. It's very annoying because I've to scan all the generated script to check that it's what I want it to be. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql does not provide the RESTRICT constraint for foreign keys as this is the same as NO ACTIOn or there being no constraint defined (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Remove the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE lines and you should be good

Comment: That is not the point, cause it happens on all constraints, being RESTRICT, SETNULL or CASCADE. The point is that propel interprets that  all fields change when not at all: